# how to calculate sum of numbers in a string of list using python

Tags: python, string

how to calculate sum of numbers in a string of list using python
l=['1000',  '1000',  '100',  '30' ,'30,1,9' ]
output should be l=['1000',  '1000',  '100',  '30', '40'] how to do it using python

Comment: Do you know how to: 1) split a string into a list of strings, 2) translate a list of strings to a list of ints, 3) sum a list of ints, 4) do all above in a function, 5) apply the function to a list?

Comment: 1)AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> data = ['1000', '1000', '100', '30' ,'30,1,9' ]
>>> [str(sum(map(int, item.split(',')))) for item in data]
['1000', '1000', '100', '30', '40']
```

Comment: Without any explanation this should be a comment, not an answer. But I like this solution.

Comment: @Matthias Actually, it precisely answers the question. Any explanation could be deemed a comment (the OP is not asking for an explanation). I'm not saying this is a good (exemplary) answer, but that's because I'm lazy. To be honest, I think that suits the question.